# Invite Suggestions of good 3rd-party controls for asp.net development

Tags: asp.net

Will anyone suggest good 3rd party controls for asp.net development.

Especially gridview.tabcontrols,treeview.Menu

Please suggest controls which scores well on all points below

1. Easy development,
2. good performance in run time.
3. Less page overhead and less page
   objects etc.
4. faster page loading.

I used few but had bad experience on page performance.

Thanks 
Swapna MC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus here at SO seems to be [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/).  [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) and [ComponentArt](http://www.componentart.com/) are good, too.  DevExpress seems to be the fastest performer.

Answer (score 0):

How about "obout" controls.

This is suggested by some one .But i am facing performance issues now.Page load is very slow.I am not sure its the controls causing the problem.

swapna

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with Telerik and DevExpress.  As others have noted, DevExpress is probably the fastest; however, I still strongly prefer Telerik.  Their big advantage is that they have been around a very long time and have a huge support database.  Compared to every other  .Net control library I've worked with, theirs is, by far, the easiest to get help for.

Considering that each library will have its own nuances and bugs, going with the one with the most vibrant user community and support forum is a smart move.

One more point, DevExpress's AspXPivotGrid is fantastic.  Clients absolutely love pivot grids, and they are a smart move for the first report and clients will cut you a lot of slack when they can build their own reports.

Comment: Thanks a lot i shall test Devexpress controls

Answer (score 0):

telerik asp.net ajax controls provide a quite rich client-side api. it's their most attractive side for me.